# Find the value of $(a+b-c)/(a+b+c)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> Given $$2a^2 +17b^2 + 8c^2 -6ab -20bc =0 \\ abc \neq 0.$$ 
>   Find the value of $(a+b-c)/(a+b+c)$.

I tried factorizing the equation, but still can't find a solution

Comment: In what way have you tried factorising the equation? Perhaps taking out $a+b+c$ as a factor and looking at the remainder would be useful?

Comment: On second thoughts, I'm not sure that would get you anywhere

Comment: I tried making LHS part as sum of squares terms so that they can be equated to 0 and I could find some relation between a,b and c. I am stuck here though

Comment: According to [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2a%5E2%2B17b%5E2%2B8c%5E2-6ab-20bc%3D0), $(a,b,c)=(6,4,5)$ works, so the answer is $\frac 1 3$. Now we just need to prove it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$0=2\cdot LHS=(2a-3b)^2+(5b-4c)^2$$
and so $2a=3b$ and $5b=4c$. This gives $$\frac{a+b-c}{a+b+c}=\frac{3b/2+b+5b/4}{3b/2+b-5b/4}=1/3.$$

Comment: How did you see that?

Comment: I just wanted to ask, how did you thought of the fact that multiplying 2 would complete the square in LHS?

Comment: I observed $(6,4,5)$ was a solution, so I tried to find a sum of squares that vanishes on this point. Because the 17 was annoying, and 34=9+25 it seemed like a good idea to multilply by 2.

Comment: Very pretty, well spotted on the lack of $ac$ term?  +1